# How to adapt a "display: table" responsive layout for tablet scaling

Tags: javascript, responsive-design, css-float, grid-layout, css-tables

I've been trying to develop a responsive grid layout that meets the following criteria:

- non-specified, content-based height
- matching heights for each content block in a row
- ability to convert layout from say four content blocks in a row to two separate rows of two

After looking around for a while, I found the "solution" of setting it up as follows:

```
    <div style="display: table;">
        <div style="display: table-cell;"> Some Content with 25% width </div>
        <div style="display: table-cell;"> Some Content with 25% width </div>
        <div style="display: table-cell;"> Some Content with 25% width </div>
        <div style="display: table-cell;"> Some Content with 25% width </div>
    </div>
```

This met all of my needs regarding height issues, but I have no idea what the best solution is for getting the divs to switch to more of a float method of dropping to the next row when they each convert to a width of 50% for tablet since the display: table; method keeps them all in the same row.

I have a feeling I'll need to incorporate some JavaScript as I can't think of another way to get content within a row to wrap below; does anyone know of an efficient way of doing this? There's going to be a fair bit of content on this site, and I'm worried that it's going to take way too long to check through each of the elements before rendering the page.

Hopefully, this all makes sense since I'm a bit out of it at the moment. If I need to clarify any details, let me know. Any and all help is appreciated as I'm a bit stumped. Thanks!

Comment: _“since the display: table; method keeps them all in the same row”_ – well then simply _drop_ (read: overwrite) the display value in your media query that you want to apply the smaller screen formatting with …

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I had considered this (if I understand you correctly), but that would cause the remaining content in the row to no longer scale to the same height.

Comment: You could try to fix that using another method for (simulating) same hight, some faux columns trick or other; or you could insert additional markup, so that each two divs in a row are grouped by more divs, and then have them display as two table cells in a row each containing another two tables with two cells on big screens (but that’s kinda ugly). Maybe its worth looking into a flexbox solution instead.